# All framework and static library files compiled to app?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, frameworks, static-libraries

1、I am wondering whether Xcode compile all the .m sources of frameworks and .a to my app, for example, if I import UIKit framework and I only using UIButton.h, will all files in UIKit be compiled to my app? what about static library?

2、And if I import some frameworks in building my own static library, will the files of frameworks be compiled into .a?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking to standard frameworks like UIKit won't add any extra data to your binary. All of the standard frameworks are part of the OS so you're only making a reference to these frameworks. However, any custom static libraries will have to be included because that compiled code is not a part of the OS.

The same thing goes for your own library. Importing standard frameworks should not increase the size of your .a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I import JSONkit.h/.m in static library, it will be compiled into .a file, if other project uses my .a file and the project also imports JSONkit, there maybe some problems(duplicate)? Or we must not compile third party libraries into static library?

Comment: I have not encountered any problems with duplicates between static libraries and code. I tested it and it worked for me. However, I don't see why you would purposely duplicate the code if you don't have to.